# IOS/Objective-C: Autolayout constraints interfere with reusing tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableview with a custom cell containing images that vary by item.  Some items have images.  For items without images, rather than use a placeholder I would like to shrink the cell and have no images at all.

Before I introduced autolayout and using a placeholder image, the images loaded properly.  However, since I have introduced autolayout and used autolayout to shrink cells that lack an image, I have run into problems with images appearing in rows where they don't belong.  I think this is because dequeuing is not working

Has anyone encountered this before?  Happy to share more code but it is just boilerplate.  The problem arises when I add the autolayout constraints.

To accomplish self-sizing I have placed

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400;
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

at bottom of viewdidload.

My cellforrowatindexpath is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    IDFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Feed* feed = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[IDFeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                        reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
if (self.feed.picname.length>=1) {
cell.messageImage.image = [self loadImageNamed:itempicname];
}
else {
cell.messageImage.image = nil;
}
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you designed cell programatically or in storyboard?

Comment: Can you show where did you set image? I see you don't use `feed` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to do anything.

Comment: Constraints are in storyboard

Comment: setting image straightforward--have edited

Comment: You're getting a local feed from the fetched results, but later access self.feed - that seems wrong.

Comment: You are correct.  My local variable was overwriting the ivar.  However, I fixed this and the issue with the images not changing remains.

Comment: I set a breakpoint where the image is set in cellforrow.. and, interestingly, after the first screen's worth of cells (three), the subsequent cells appear as empty.  This is my first experience setting a breakpoint in a cell so don't know what that means.  Perhaps it always happens when you are reusing cells.

Comment: Also, when I use a placeholder image instead of nil, it works okay.

Comment: Solved it.  IF ANYONE HAS THIS PROBLEM AGAIN, MAKE SURE YOU USE FORMULATION cell.messageImage.image = nil;, not cell.messageImage = nil;.  If you set the actual imageView to nil, the autconstratints will not work properly.  You need to set the imageView.image to nil.  Just wasted three days of my life on this.....